# How can I port this JavaScript logic as a single-line RegEx to be used in PHP?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to recreate the following conditions to validate string syntax in a single RegEx to be used with PHP.  What would be the fastest regular expression to use, returning *TRUE* if these conditions are all met?

- String must not be empty
- Total string length: `>= 3` and `<= 16` characters
- Allowed characters in string: `a-z`,`0-9`,`-`,`.`
- No upper case letters allowed
- First character must be a lower case letter: `a-z`
- Last character must be a lower case letter or digit: `a-z` or `0-9`
- Cannot have two consecutive hyphens `-` anywhere in string

**Bonus Trickyness**: If a dot/period `.` exists, the string becomes segmented using the `.` as a delimiter.  These "segments" have special rules:

- All previous rules also still apply to the string as a whole
- Segment must start with a letter: `a-z`
- Segment end with a letter or digit: `a-z` `0-9`
- Segment can only have letters, digits, or hyphens: `a-z` `0-9` `-`
- Segment must be `=> 3` characters long

This "segment" logic is really throwing me for a loop (no pun intended).  I'm not sure how to incorporate everything together.

---

Here's an example of JavaScript that achieves the goal.  I am working in PHP and need a single line RegEx that will validate TRUE if all criteria is met.  I don't need the logic to return *why* it failed (out of scope).  I only need a `TRUE/FALSE` RegEx.  Just leaving this snippet in case it is helpful:

```
export function validateAccountName(value) {
  let i, label, len, suffix;

  suffix = "Account name should ";
  if (!value) {
    return suffix + "not be empty.";
  }
  const length = value.length;
  if (length < 3) {
    return suffix + "be longer.";
  }
  if (length > 16) {
    return suffix + "be shorter.";
  }
  if (/\./.test(value)) {
    suffix = "Each account segment should ";
  }
  const ref = value.split(".");
  for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
    label = ref[i];
    if (!/^[a-z]/.test(label)) {
      return suffix + "start with a letter.";
    }
    if (!/^[a-z0-9-]*$/.test(label)) {
      return suffix + "have only letters, digits, or dashes.";
    }
    if (/--/.test(label)) {
      return suffix + "have only one dash in a row.";
    }
    if (!/[a-z0-9]$/.test(label)) {
      return suffix + "end with a letter or digit.";
    }
    if (!(label.length >= 3)) {
      return suffix + "be longer";
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should add few valid and invalid samples

Comment: My personal opinion: If you cannot make such a reg-exp yourself, you will probably have difficulty understanding it, modify it later, and maintaining it. Normal code would probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a positive lookahead to assert the length, including the first and last character, and another negative lookahead to assert not 2 consecutive hyphens.

```
^(?=[a-z][a-z\d.-]{1,14}[a-z\d]$)(?!.*--)[a-z\d-]+(?:\.[a-z][a-z\d-]+[a-z\d])*$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-z][a-z\d.-]{1,14}[a-z\d]$)` Positive lookahead to assert 3-16 chars, starting with a-z and end with a-z\d
- `(?!.*--)` Negative lookahead to assert not `--`
- `[a-z\d-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed chars (without a dot)
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.[a-z][a-z\d-]+[a-z\d]` Match a `.` and repeat segments of at least 3 chars starting with a-z, then 1+ times any of the listed without a dot and ending on a-z\d without the hyphen
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RwTCKp/1)

If all the parts should be at least 3 chars when there is a dot present, you can repeat matching at least 3 character and shorten the pattern a bit by repeating the first group using `(?1)` or [see the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/aKLPCT/1) without the group.

```
^(?=[a-z][a-z\d.-]{1,14}[a-z\d]$)(?!.*--)([a-z][a-z\d-]+[a-z\d]+)(?:\.(?1))*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7zg3yr/1)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this regex as well:

```sh
^[a-z](?!.*--)(?!.*\.([^.]{0,2}(\.|$)|[.\d-]))[a-z.\d-]{1,14}[a-z\d]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7IU9jG/1/)

**RegEx Explained:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-z]`: Match a `a-z` character
- `(?!.*--)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if 2 consecutive hyphen are found anywhere
- `(?!.*\.([^.]{0,2}(\.|$)|[.\d-]))`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if there are less than 3 non-dot characters after a dot or a non-alpha character after dot
- `[a-z.\d-]{1,14}`: Match 1 to 14 instances of a `a-z` or a digit or a dor or a hyphen character
- `[a-z\d]`: Match a `a-z` or digit
- `$`: End